# Android Studio não reconhece imagens

Tags: android-studio, imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Gente, meu Android Studio aqui não está reconhecendo as imagens que coloquei na pasta drawable. Arrastei pra lá seis imagens, três delas eu consegui acessar normalmente,as outras três eu não consigo. Alguma ideia? Pra testar tentei adicionar outras imagens e acessá-las e também não consegui.

São todas png, todos os nomes em lowercase. Detalhe: Se eu não tento acessar essas imagens, o projeto compila normalmente. Link para o projeto problemático se alguém tiver curiosidade:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/62cocsmfihgnjgp/MyTools.zip?dl=0

Comment: A extensão de todas as suas imagens são iguais?

Comment: Sim sim, todas iguais! Nomes todas em lower case também!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra referenciar as imagens da pasta `drawable`, o correto é utilizar `R.drawable.recurso`

Comment: Jesus amado! Funcionou! Cara, muito obrigado! Estava fazendo assim porque aprendi assim no curso que estou fazendo aqui (online). Valeu demais, tenho umas duas horas que tento descobrir o problema.

Comment: Fico feliz por ter funcionado! Lembre-se de aceitar as respostas que te ajudarem para que pessoas que também tiverem o mesmo problema consigam achar mais facilmente uma solução. =)

Answer (score 0):

Dá uma olhada qual o formato da imagem, talvez elas possam estar num formato que o android studio não consiga ler, tente usar sempre .png, pra mudar o formato você pode usar o photoshop ou qualquer outro programa que o faça.

Comment: Estao todas no formato png, muito estranho!

Comment: você poderia postar um print de como fica no app ou parte do codigo, assim posso t ajudar melhor

Comment: Postei lá em cima! Coloquei o projeto no dropbox também! Na imagem vc pode ver que as outras imagens sao reconhecidas normalmente. Add todas juntas, já tentei renomear, recolocar na pasta, colocar outras imagens e ainda nada.